# Custom AuthenticationManager

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I decided to use customized AutenticationManager for my unit test. Here is what I have put together in my test context file so far:

```
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
 <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:ldap.properties"/>
</beans:bean>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" >
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>  

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthProvider"> 
    <user-service>
<user name="department1000" password="password" authorities="ROLE_1000" />
<user name="alldepartments"    password="password2" authorities="ROLE_ALL_DEPT_ACCESS" />
<user name="esssaa"    password="password3" authorities="ROLE_STUDENT" />
```

```
<beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="fi.utu.security.PermissionEvaluatorImpl"/>
```

This causes 
   Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot have child elements when    used with 'ref' attribute

Do I need some custom class for customized userDetailsService, or can I somehow make it work as autowire bean with spring classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `user-service` in an `authentication-provider` element and terminate the previous element correctly:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthProvider" /> 
    <authentication-provider> 
        <user-service>
           ...
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: That's good. But do you need any references to UserDetailsSservice when using user-service-tag?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `user-service` defines an embedded list of users, usually for testing. It doesn't have a `ref` attribute. Also, take a look at the [namespace appendix docs for authentication-provider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-authentication-provider).

Comment: When I leave the reference out, I get error saying no autencation provider found.

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to see without seeing the configuration. Please edit your question to add the configuration you're talking about.